# dos select consecutivos

Tags: php, html, mysql

Necesito hacer este ejercicio en un solo archivo y solo con php. Tengo dos combobox con dos botones, uno detrás de cada combo. El primer combo se carga bien de una tabla de mysql. Al darle al primer botón se carga el segundo combo con una consulta que se crea con la elección del primero y al darle al segundo botón aparece una tabla con datos de la base de datos.
El problema es que no me guarda las variables que selecciono en los combos al darle a los botones. Este es el código que he hecho hasta ahora.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>WORLD</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            define("SERVIDOR","localhost");
            define("USUARIO","root");
            define("CLAVE","");
            $BD="world";
            $db;
            try{
                if($BD!='')
                    $db=new PDO("mysql:host=".SERVIDOR.";dbname=".$BD.";charset=utf8",USUARIO,CLAVE,array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND=>"SET NAMES 'utf8'"));
                else
                    $db=new PDO("mysql:host=".SERVIDOR.";charset=utf8",USUARIO,CLAVE,array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND=>"SET NAMES 'utf8'"));
                $db->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY,true);
                $db->setAttribute(PDO::NULL_TO_STRING,true);
                if($BD==''){
                    $sql=file_get_contents('world.sql');
                    $this->ejecuta_SQL($sql);
                }
            }catch(PDOException $e){
                die("<p><h3>No se ha podido establecer la conexión.
                    <p>Compruebe si está activado el servidor de bases de
                    datos MySQL.</h3></p>\n<p>Error: ".$e->getMessage()."</p>\n");
            }
            $region="";
            $name="";
            echo "<h1>EJERCICIO CONSULTA DE PAISES POR REGIONES</h1>
                <form name='form1' method='post' action=\"index.php\">";
            $sql1='SELECT Region FROM country';
            $resultado1=$db->query($sql1);
            echo "Selecciona Region: <select name='campo_busqueda1'>
                <option>Selecciona...</option>";
            while(($fila1=$resultado1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))!=NULL){
                echo '<option value="'.$fila1["Region"].'">'.$fila1["Region"].'</option>';
            };
            $region=$_POST['campo_busqueda1'];
            //$region=isset($_POST["campo_busqueda1"]) ? $_POST["campo_busqueda1"] : "";
            echo "</select>";
            echo "<input type='submit' value='Enviar'><br>";
            $sql2='SELECT Name FROM country WHERE Region="'.$region.'"';
            $resultado2=$db->query($sql2);
            echo "Selecciona Pais: <select name='campo_busqueda2'>
                <option>Selecciona...</option>";
            while(($fila2=$resultado2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))!=NULL){
                echo '<option value="'.$fila2["Name"].'">'.$fila2["Name"].'</option>';
            };
            $name=$_POST['campo_busqueda2'];
            //$name=isset($_POST["campo_busqueda2"]) ? $_POST["campo_busqueda2"] : "";
            echo "</select>";
            echo "<input type='submit' value='Enviar'><br>
            </form>";
        ?>
        <table border=1>
            <tr>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Poblacion</th>
            </tr>
                <?php
                    $sql3='SELECT city.Name,city.Population FROM city as city INNER JOIN country AS country ON city.CountryCode=country.Code
                        WHERE (country.Region="'.$region.'") AND (country.Name="'.$name.'")';
                    $resultado3=$db->query($sql3);
                    echo $region;
                    echo $name;
                    echo $resultado3;
                    while($row=$resultado3->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                        echo $row;
                        print_r($row);
                        echo '<tr><td>'.$row[0].'</td><td>'.$row[1].'</td></tr>';
                    }
                ?>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para determinar la opción seleccionada debes usar la información guardada en el post, lo que puedes hacer es preguntar si existe y si coincide con la opción marcarla como seleccionada. Para ello cambias la variable en la que recoges el valor del post a antes del select. Te pongo un ejemplo con el primer select, habría que hacer lo mismo en el segundo.

```
$sql1='SELECT Region FROM country';
$resultado1=$db->query($sql1);
$region=$_POST['campo_busqueda1'];
echo "Selecciona Region: <select name='campo_busqueda1'>
    <option>Selecciona...</option>";
    while(($fila1=$resultado1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))!=NULL){  
       if ($region && $fila1["Region"]==$region) { $seleccionado="selected"; } else {$seleccionado ="";}
       echo '<option value="'.$fila1["Region"].'" '.$seleccionado.'>'.$fila1["Region"].'</option>';
                };
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Me ha sido muy útil.